# Google Home/Assistant - How to create "Works With Google" Device that can be added to Google Home "ecosystem"?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assistant

I have Google Home with Google Assistant throughout my house. I can control various smart devices as expected, but I have developed a few of my own devices which I would like to add to my existing ecosystem (controlled with NodeMCU controllers and various embedded linux systems).

I would like to avoid having to use Tasmota or other firmwares which force me to work within a narrow pre-defined action space, so please do not suggest this.

I am currently controlling my devices by using IFTTT to send a text ingredient to a home-server, which parses the text and sends out commands accordingly. However, this is limiting, as it requires a specific trigger phrase, and the devices cannot be "added" to my Google Home Devices, so I cannot control them directly on my Google Hub or phone.

How can I create a "Works With Google" device which can be added to my Google Home ecosystem? For instance, a light bulb or other PWM-controlled device which shows up as a device with 0-100% "brightness", or blinds which can be from 0-100% open. I understand I will need to implement methods to report the device's current state (amount brightness/open,  for example), and also implement methods for the device to accept commands.

I have looked at the Google Assistant SDK examples, but it appears to be geared towards running Google Assistant itself on various devices, rather than adding "Works With Google" devices or control layers to existing product control software. There are some examples which show adding devices, but they require changes to the Google Assistant installation itself. And since I am using a pre-built Google Hub, I cannot modify the software it is running.

Any examples or other resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking up [Google's smart home documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview), for controlling devices with the Google Assistant, which is the "Works with Google".

There are [codelabs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/codelabs) and [sample projects](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/samples) to help you get started.